# How to tell if a hardware RNG is rigged?

Tags: random-number-generator, cryptographic-hardware

On a related note of [building my own RNG](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/21186/how-to-roll-my-own-hardware-rng), as someone suggested to use several commericial solutions how can I check if it is rigged against me? (although I am still strongly biased to a homebrew solution that is designed to be hard to subvert, taking the shortest possible route from a quantum random source to the ADC)

Comment: No way to tell really. The output of a CSPRNG would be indistinguishable from a TRNG. Only by inspecting what the actual hardware does would you be able to verify it.

Comment: @otus I am okay with a good CSPRNG with a good entropy feed. The problem is about subverted RNGs like the ECDRBG NSA backdoor. How can I tell if my commercial RNG chip is rigged in that way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While unfortunately that is not possible deterministically, if you have a small amount of "guaranteed trustworthy" randomness, you can use several untrusted RNGs together to generate an unlimited supply of good randomness (under some weak assumptions of non-signaling between the RNGs). This is called "randomness expansion" and I am not aware of any use in practice yet, unfortunately.

See these papers by [Colbeck and Kent](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.4474) and [Coudron and Yuen](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6755)